# Adding question and name variable to code - Python

Tags: python-3.x

Thanks for reading my post.  I'd be really grateful if someone can help me with my problem.  I'm trying to add a rather simple thing to my code but keep getting issues.

Before the user is presented with the questions of the quiz I would like to to great them e.g. Welcome to the Quiz and then ask them their name and save it has a variable to use later in the code e.g. Well done Gary you score 5 out of 5.

Please if you can help I would be so happy.  Thanks in advance.

```
  class Question:
     def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
          self.prompt = prompt
          self.answer = answer



question_prompts = [
    "Which of these will help keep you safe when using a chat room or an internet forum?\n(A)Always tell your friends your password.\n(B)Use the same password for everything.\n(C)Change your password regularly.\n(D)Make your passwords easy to guess.\n\n",

    "Who should you tell if something or someone on the internet upsets you?\n(A)Only your friends.\n(B)Only your bother or sister.\n(C)Nobody.\n(D)Your parents or a member of staff.\n\n",

    "When is it safe to use a webcam?\n(A)You should never use a webcam.\n(B)When talking to people you know in the real world.\n(C)When talking to people you only know through the internet.\n(D)When talking to anyone.\n\n",

    "What is cyber bullying?\n(A)When anyone uses the internet, a mobile, or other technology to deliberately upset someone.\n(B)When someone sends you an e-mail giving you the answers to your homework.\n(C)When someone disagrees with your opinion on an internet forum\n(D)When someone is nasty to a robot\n\n",

    "How can you protect your computer from viruses?\n(A)Never click e-mail links or open attachments from people you don't know.\n(B)Always remember to log off when you are finished using the computer.\n(C)Do nothing - your computer will protect itself\n(D)Give it antibiotics.\n\n",




]

questions = [
     Question(question_prompts[0], "C"),
     Question(question_prompts[1], "D"),
     Question(question_prompts[2], "B"),
     Question(question_prompts[3], "A"),
     Question(question_prompts[4], "A"),

]




def run_quiz(questions):
     score = 0
     for question in questions:
          answer = input(question.prompt)
          if answer == question.answer:
               score += 1
     print("you got", score, "out of", len(questions))
     if score == 5:
          print("Well done you answered all the questions correctly")
     if score == 4:
          print("Well done you got most of the questions correctly")
     if score == 3:
          print("Not bad going.  You answered most of the questions correctly")
     if score <= 2:
          print("Let's try doing the quiz again.")

run_quiz(questions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the name from the user before calling `run_quiz(questions)` and pass the name as argument to the function. Inside the function, display the username along with score.

Here is the updated code.

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer


question_prompts = [
    "Which of these will help keep you safe when using a chat room or an internet forum?\n(A)Always tell your friends your password.\n(B)Use the same password for everything.\n(C)Change your password regularly.\n(D)Make your passwords easy to guess.\n\n",

    "Who should you tell if something or someone on the internet upsets you?\n(A)Only your friends.\n(B)Only your bother or sister.\n(C)Nobody.\n(D)Your parents or a member of staff.\n\n",

    "When is it safe to use a webcam?\n(A)You should never use a webcam.\n(B)When talking to people you know in the real world.\n(C)When talking to people you only know through the internet.\n(D)When talking to anyone.\n\n",

    "What is cyber bullying?\n(A)When anyone uses the internet, a mobile, or other technology to deliberately upset someone.\n(B)When someone sends you an e-mail giving you the answers to your homework.\n(C)When someone disagrees with your opinion on an internet forum\n(D)When someone is nasty to a robot\n\n",

    "How can you protect your computer from viruses?\n(A)Never click e-mail links or open attachments from people you don't know.\n(B)Always remember to log off when you are finished using the computer.\n(C)Do nothing - your computer will protect itself\n(D)Give it antibiotics.\n\n",
]

questions = [
     Question(question_prompts[0], "C"),
     Question(question_prompts[1], "D"),
     Question(question_prompts[2], "B"),
     Question(question_prompts[3], "A"),
     Question(question_prompts[4], "A"),

]


def run_quiz(questions, user_name):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("Hey ", user_name, " you got", score, "out of", len(questions))
    if score == 5:
        print("Well done you answered all the questions correctly")
    if score == 4:
        print("Well done you got most of the questions correctly")
    if score == 3:
        print("Not bad going.  You answered most of the questions correctly")
    if score <= 2:
        print("Let's try doing the quiz again.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_name = input("Welcome to the quiz.\nEnter your name:")
    run_quiz(questions, user_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Mithilesh42.  Ran the code and it does just what I wanted.